# Why is my button not being the color I'm telling it to be?

Tags: html, css, button, colors, hover

I'm trying to make my button 1) be red, and 2) become green upon hover/mouse over. **Here's my HTML:**

```html
 <div id="home-button"> <button type="button" style="height: 100px; width: 400px; font-size: 45px; font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif; border-radius:20px" href='/'> HOME </button> </div>
```

HOME

**Here's my css:**

```
#home-button {
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
  color: red;
}

#home-button:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

As you can see, the button is neither red nor green. Please tell me why

Answer (score 1):

Target the button itself

```css
#home-button button{
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
  color: red;
}

#home-button:hover button{
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-button"> <button type="button" style="height: 100px; width: 400px; font-size: 45px; font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif; border-radius:20px" href='/'> HOME </button> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a button that's red and turns green on hover.

```html
<style>
#home-button {
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
}

#home-button button {
background-color: red;
}

#home-button button:hover {
background-color: green;
}
</style>

 <div id="home-button"> <button type="button" style="height: 100px; width: 400px; font-size: 45px; font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif; border-radius:20px" href='/'> HOME </button> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The css selector is incorrect. You are only selecting the div[id="home-button"] and not affecting the button you want to change. Your css selector should be #home-button button and #home-button button:hover.